# Trying to extract data form SQL using PS script

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have been trying to get a PS script to work in extracting files (pdf, word, etc.) from an SQL Server database. I came across the PowerShell script below. The script runs and populates the destination folder but all files are 0 bytes and during the script execution. It throws the error:

> "Exporting Objects from FILESTREAM container: .docx
> Exception calling "GetBytes" with "5" argument(s): "Invalid attempt to GetBytes on column 'extension'.  The GetBytes function can only be used on columns of typ
> e Text, NText, or Image.""

Can anyone point me in what am I doing wrong and how to fix this please? Much appreciated.

```
$Server = ".\xxxxxx";             
$Database = "xxxxxx"; 
$Dest = "C:\DATA\";     
$bufferSize = 8192;       


$Sql = "
SELECT 
      [extension]
      
  FROM [XXXXXXXX].[dbo].[XXXXXXdocuments]
"; 
 
 
$con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection; 
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;" + 
 "Integrated Security=True;" + 
 "Initial Catalog=$Database"; 
$con.Open(); 

Write-Output ((Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss) + ": Started ..."); 
 
 
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $Sql, $con; 
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 120 
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
 
 
$out = [array]::CreateInstance('Byte', $bufferSize) 
 
 
While ($rd.Read()) 
{ 
 try 
  { 
   Write-Output ("Exporting Objects from FILESTREAM container: {0}" -f $rd.GetString(0)); 
 
   $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($Dest + $rd.GetString(0)), Create, Write; 
   $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter $fs; 
 
   $start = 0; 
 

    enter code here

   $received = $rd.Getbytes(0, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1); 
   While ($received -gt 0) 
   { 
    $bw.Write($out, 0,      $received); 
    $bw.Flush(); 
    $start += $received; 
 
    $received = $rd.Getbytes(0, $start, $out, 0, $bufferSize - 1); 
   } 
   $bw.Close(); 
   $fs.Close(); 
  } 
  catch 
  { 
   Write-Output ($_.Exception.Message) 
  } 
  finally 
  { 
   $fs.Dispose();         
  }
 }  
   
 
$rd.Close(); 
$cmd.Dispose(); 
$con.Close(); 
 
Write-Output ("Finished");
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: Error appears clear regarding the data problem where the field you are trying to read cannot be called in `GetBytes()`. What is the data type of `extension` field? Remember `varchar` or `nvarchar` is not the same as `text` or `ntext`. Are you saving the binary data of PDF, DOCX, etc. in the database?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this, i managed to figure out the problem is that i was invoking columns that didnt contained the data i was trying to extract, once reviewed and corrected all works fine. Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BinaryWriter is unnecessary.  It's for writing primitive types to a Stream.

And there's no need to muck around with buffers; you can simply use `SqlDataReader.GetStream(int).CopyTo(Stream)`, eg

```
$Server = "localhost";             
$Database = "adventureworks2017"; 
$Dest = "C:\temp\";     

$Sql = "
SELECT concat('photo', ProductPhotoID, '.jpg') name, LargePhoto from Production.ProductPhoto
"; 
 
 
$con = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection; 
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$Server;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=$Database;TrustServerCertificate=true"; 
$con.Open(); 

Write-Output ((Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss) + ": Started ..."); 
  
$cmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $Sql, $con; 
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 120 
$rd = $cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

 

While ($rd.Read()) 
{ 
 try 
  { 
   Write-Output ("Exporting: {0}" -f $rd.GetString(0)); 
 
   $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($Dest + $rd.GetString(0)), Create, Write; 
   $rd.GetStream(1).CopyTo($fs) 
   $fs.Close()
  } 
  catch 
  { 
   Write-Output ($_.Exception.Message) 
  } 
  finally 
  { 
   $fs.Dispose();         
  }
 }  
   
 
$rd.Close(); 
$cmd.Dispose(); 
$con.Close(); 
 
Write-Output ("Finished");
```